# which one should be used in case of jquery ajax call, success/ error callback or done()/fail() chain function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

sometimes even if the ajax call has returned error, it calls done() chain function rather than fail().
so confused whether to use success/error callback or done()/fail() chain function.

for eg which one is advisable 1 or 2?

1. ```
   $.ajax({
     url: someurl,
     success: function(){
        //some code if ajax request is successful
     },
     error: function(){
       //some code if ajax request fails
     }
   })
   ```
2. ```
   $.ajax({
       url: someurl
   }).done(function(){
       //some code changes
   }).fail(function(){
       //some code changes
   });
   ```

Comment: _"sometimes even if the ajax call has returned error, it calls done()"_ Can you create a stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044436/jquery-ajax-request-events-done-fail-success

Answer (score 0):

These are interchangeable ways of doing an AJAX call in jQuery.  The second method you describe uses promises, whereas the first method handles successes/errors as options on the AJAX call.

Comment: which one should be used as a best practice?